# How protect my ajax from XSS vulnerability (NODE.JS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, routes, global-variables

I am doing an ajax inside my index.html for a sensitive URL, however I need to protect this URL in the client side, but I have no idea how to do this.

This URL is my database in MongoLAB.

I looked for a tutorial but i didnt find anything that help could help me.

Example:

```
    $(function(){

        var host = 'https://mysensitivemongolaburl.com';

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: host,
            success:function(data){
                data.forEach (function (something) {
                    var HTML = [];

                    HTML.push('<td>' + something.date + '</td>');
                    HTML.push('<td>' + something.date + '</td>');

                    $('something').append(HTML.join(''));
                });
            },
            error:function(e){
                //window.location = '/';
            }
        });

    });
```

I can not leave that way in my client because if i do everybody can get the URL , I need to protect it.

OBS: I'm using embed javascript (EJS) for template.

Comment: You can't "protect" the URL on the client. There are so many ways to listen to and inspect network traffic. If you really want to protect the URL you can't directly use it from the client.

Comment: is possible make this ajax on the client and them store into a object that i can access in my client from my routes??? @FelixKling

Comment: I'm don't understand what you mean by that.

Comment: I need to pull data from my database that is currently in MongoLab.com. The format is json.

As you saw in the code.. now I'm pulling this data and making a list with them through a loop with jquery. I can not use the above code because it leaves the database URL vulnerable.

I need to pull this data on my server and send to the HTML through the routes (I believe so), but i do not know where to start. @FelixKling

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/yxf7lx1.png my database in mongolab is like that @FelixKling

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you are saying is "I don't want the client to know the URL"; but then, how should the same client make a request on that URL not knowing it?

In nodejs there's [a nice library called **request**](https://github.com/request/request). What you can do is define a set of your public API and reroute the data (proxy) to the secret URL kept only on the server:

```
req.pipe(request('http://secreturl')).pipe(resp)
```

Anyways, I believe it's not a good practice to let public client access the database directly. It's better to define strict API and DB queries in nodejs, so people can't just do anything to your DB.

Answer (score -2):

Obfuscate your JS, your above code would turn into this if you don't want to show your url:

```
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return c.toString(36)};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[c.toString(a)]=k[c]||c.toString(a)}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}('$(3(){8 6=\'d://c.b\';$.9({a:\'f\',g:6,j:3(5){5.h(3(1){8 0=[];0.4(\'<2>\'+1.7+\'</2>\');0.4(\'<2>\'+1.7+\'</2>\');$(\'1\').k(0.i(\'\'))})},l:3(e){}})})',22,22,'HTML|something|td|function|push|data|host|date|var|ajax|type|com|mysensitivemongolaburl|https||GET|url|forEach|join|success|append|error'.split('|'),0,{}))
```

there are plenty of other places where you can do the same thing. you can also do it on here.

http://www.jsobfuscate.com/

or you can try the other following techniques:

```
JavaScript Beautifier – make your JavaScript code look pretty!
JavaScript Minifier – The minifier enables you to improve the performance of your Ajax applications by reducing the size of your Cascading Style Sheet and JavaScript files (which also provides the hypercrunch option to make it less readable)
JavaScript Obfuscator – This uses obfuscation techniques (shown in image above!). Nice.
encode base 64 – http://www.shell-tools.net/index.php?op=base64_enc
decode base 64 – http://www.shell-tools.net/index.php?op=base64_dec
http://jsutility.pjoneil.net/ – JavaScript Utility Version 3 – Obfuscation Program
```

in my opinion you can't do much about the front-end besides js/jquery code obfuscation. Have you thought of 
authenticating the users? you are going to get random people viewing your page if its going to be public.

Comment: this is not a bad idea, but if i use http://jsbeautifier.org/ i can 'uncrack' the code...

Comment: the page is already authenticate with facebook passport. only authorized people can see the content. But protecting a route does not protect the url in the ajax.. so the vulnerability continues..

Comment: not always. you need to properly escape your inputs. that's how you protect the url.